# Multiplication with a simplexml_load_file() object doesn't work

Tags: php, xml, for-loop, foreach, multiplication

I extract values from an `XML` with `PHP`

```
<?php 

    $url = 'list.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    $entries = $xml->item;
    $i = 0;
    $total = 1;

    foreach($entries as $entry){
        $i++;
        $number[$i] = $entry->total;
        $total *= $number[$i];
    }

    echo $total;

?>
```

How can I build a total based on each $number extracted from the XML? Right now, my total is zero.

So for all loops together something like:

```
$total = $number[1] * $number[2] * $number[3] * $number[4] ....
```

Comment: initialize `$total` before the loop with 0 and in the loop use `*=` operator

Comment: hm, I get only 0 if I echo out the $total inside each loop: $total *= $number[$i]; and then echo $total;

Comment: 1. `$totoal = 0;` before the foreach loop 2. in the foreach loop: `$total *= $number[$i];` 3. after the foreach loop: `echo $total;` do you get 0 if you use this? (IF yes one of the number is 0)

Comment: yes, I still get 0. I have different numbers, but all are larger than 0, so like: 1.534, 12.934, 0.012, 0.1323, 6.124, ...

Comment: It has to work! can you please post what value all numbers have? If they are too many post only a few

Comment: 1.2471, 0.6356, 1.5143, 7.8182, 0.9735, 0.84, 19.2042, 0.0652, 1622.9036, 0.0871, 0.0012, 0.6101

Comment: lol sry my mistake xD! you have to initalize $total with 1! This was the number which was 0 :D it should work if you initalize `$total with 1`

Comment: lol, nope, tried that myself too earlier, still get 0 :D

Comment: The posted values are these all values or just a few?

Comment: these are all. none of the values i receive are 0. maybe i need to convert them again to a number format? which wouldn't make sense, since they come in as a number in the XML already: <total>1.2471</total>

Comment: So if you put a "echo" before the assignment in the loop you get these values? (Sry for the question, but it makes no sense to my, it should work)

Comment: see updated code above. strangely, the first echo of $total for loop 1 is 1 but turns to 0 in loop 2 and i don't see why

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66860/discussion-between-rizier123-and-rainerbrunotte).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

(You have to cast the return of `simplexml_load_file()` to `double`)

```
$url = "list.xml"; 
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 

$entries = $xml->results->rate; 
$count = 0; 
$total = 1; 
$number = array(); 

foreach($entries as $entry){ 
    $count++; 
    $number[$count] = $entry->Bid; 
    $total *= (double)$number[$count]; 
} 

echo "Total: " . $total;
```